# не получается установить сборку Skype4COM

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

Пытаюсь запустить проект, в котором используется библиотека Skype4COM, но отсутствует референс на неё и она сама тоже. Попытка поставить через nuget приводит к ошибке:
Install-Package : Не удалось установить пакет «Skype4COM 1.0.1». Вы пытаетесь установить этот пакет в проект, требуемая версия платформы которого — «.
NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1», но в пакете нет ссылок на сборки или файлов содержимого, совместимых с этой платформой. Дополнительную информацию можно 
получить у автора пакета.At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Skype4COM
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: ( [Install-Package], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Пробовал разные версии .Net framework - от 3.0 до 4.6.1 - не помогло. Что ещё могу сделать? Гуглил и пытался найти прямую dll - не помогло

Comment: Искать пакет или dll для версии NETFramework установленной у вас, предполагаю что это NETFramework,Version=v4.0

Comment: И по любому, откройте нугет пакет архиваторов, это зип файл, и извлеките нужное из него :)